# How standard is HMAC(SHA-1)

Tags: security, hash, hmac, hmacsha1

HMAC(SHA-1) is an algorithm for Hash computation that also accepts a key as input value. The algorithm follows certain rules and guarantees a certain level of security and resilience against attacks.

Moving to its implementation: is HMAC(SHA-1) standard at the point that all the "official" and correct implementations of it produce exactly the same result for a given input message and key? Or is the algorithm accepting different implementations that might produce a different result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any given implementation of HMAC-SHA1 will produce the same set of bytes given the same set of bytes as the input message and key.

That said, there can be a lot of variation on how various interfaces work and how they accept those bytes.  For example, one library may output the hash as a hex string, and another may output it as an array of bytes.  Or one would take a string as input with a UTF-8 encoding, whereas another would take it in as a UTF-16 encoding.  You would need to be careful that the same bytes are hitting the algorithm in different libraries to ensure you get the same result.

Also, while HMAC-SHA1 is probably okay from a security perspective, you should probably be using HMAC-SHA256 instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's very standard.  It's a standard, even!

[RFC2104](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) specifies the actual HMAC algorithm and block sizes.

[RFC2202](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2202.html) contains test cases for both HMAC-MD5 and HMAC-SHA1.

For further study, [RFC4868](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4868) gives more guidance on HMAC for the SHA2 family, with an emphasis on IPSec.